# New URL after doing redirect using 301

Tags: 301-redirect, googlebot

If we do a redirect 301, one my expired job to another URL in my site, Google will record this redirection. But what if this original job URL appears again say after 1 year. Will Google remember this redirection even after a year or so?

Answer (score 2):

no, google will not remember redirection. Every time a googlebot does it's run (periodically on known content, or via "add url" suggestion) and sees some URL, it will try to fetch it.

as a result it can get:

- "200" (with a content) and then index that content
- "404" or "410" (not found) in which case it will remove (after some time and more retries to make sure it's not a mistake) page from cache
- "301" (redirect), in which case it will simply fetch new page pointed by redirect URL and repeat whole process.

So, no, it's not a problem. If later you want to reuse/reactivate that page, you simply remove 301 redirect and create content - googlebot will pick it up as soon as it finds the page - via link on some other page, or if page is (unlikely) not linked at all, via manual [add url](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) submission on google

Check [google own answer](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93636?hl=en&ref_topic=2371325) (and/or verify yourself on unimportant test page) for reference on feasibility of reversing 301 redirects...

Comment: Do you have any references to prop up your answer?

Comment: @AgA updated answer with reference from google webmaster tools help

Comment: But this page talks about only full domain redirects using 301.

Comment: @AgA it doesn't matter where the 301 points to (same host or some other), the point was that the google will NOT remember forever 301 redirect, but will try to refetch URLs that were made 301 at some time, and will process them normally if redirect is gone at a later time. If that was what you were asking (if that was not what you wanted to know, please try to explain in more detail what *exactly* is worrying you, and why this answer does not explain it)